# Что такое сокет в сетевом программировании и какие у него свойста?

Tags: сокет

Здравствуйте,
У меня появилась необходимость вручную управлять сокетами,однако ни одной статьи на эту тему я не нашел, за два тяжелых дня. А именно, не как вызывать готовенькую апи под названием сокет, а (грубо говоря) самолично написать такоую вот апи функцию.
Нужно это для проекта на Arduino и Ethernet шилда "W5100", но это я вам говорю только для того чтобы указать на то, что работаю не с API Windows или чем-то еще подобным и управлять мне ими придется в ручную, так как популярный и единственно работающий (у меня) драйвер отвратительнейшим образом управляет этими сокетами. Выливается это в 10 секундные задержки при обращении по сети.

Вопрос по сути сводится к просьбе указать на источник где можно изучить этот вопрос в доль и поперек: Как создавать сокеты, сколько они живут (до конца TCP сесси или...?), на основании чего выдается решение, что нужен новый сокет; какой дать ему номер; как(косвенно) определить, что сокет еще занят (или заблокирован?) и так далее. 
Вобщем хочется изучить их так чтобы управлять ими как продолжением своей руки.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793

Comment: @edem Спасибо вам большое за ссылку, она оказалась очень полезна. Если вы напишите это как ответ я приму его как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство данных вопросов покрывает непосредственно сам стандарт для TCP (RFC 793), где описывается структура сокетов и взаимодействие с ними.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793 - оригинальный текст (англ) стандарта;
- http://www.protocols.ru/files/RFC/rfc-793.pdf - один из переводов на русский язык.